# Is there a specific way of using anchor tags in React?

Tags: reactjs, anchor

I am trying to use an anchor tag in my react application, like this:  `<a href="www.someWebsite.com"> click here </a>`, but is not working (the text changes into blue, but it doesn't go anywhere). I wonder if there is a specific "react" way of doing this. I even tried `<Link to="www.someWebsite.com"> click here </Link>` (while importing react router) but it didn't work. How are 'anchor tags' supposed to work in React.js?

Comment: An <a> tag should work, try putting in the http://

Answer (score 0):

try this

> ```
> <a  href="https://www.google.com">click </a>
> ```